# Android custom animation where the animation velocity changes with time

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want to create a custom android animation where the animation velocity first increases for time t1 and then velocity becomes constant for time t1 and then velocity decreases for time t3(rest of the time.).

I have tried combination of accelerate, linear and decelerate translate animation but it dint worked the way I wanted. 
I want to have the full control over the animation and its velocity/acceleration for entire duration

Comment: read about Interpolators then

Answer (score 0):

Just simply create a translation animation and then in code set the interpolator to be an `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.html) for more info.

Comment: AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator does not exactly match the requirements. It does not provide the linear/zero acceleration for some time which is the requirement.